# Weird margin on html page

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]
There seems to be padding around the sides of my website, and I cannot get rid of it. Any types of hints will be appreciated.

```css
#introContainer{
 background-color: #bdc3c7;
}

#navHeader{
 background-color:#95a5a6;

}

#skillsHeader{
 background-color:#3498db;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
 <title>Local</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="introContainer">
 </div>

 <div id="navHeader">
 </div>

 <div id="skillsHeader">
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Either write something like `body * { margin:0; padding:0; }` or make use of a *reset.css* to minimize weird behaviour between different browsers. Also your problem should get fixed like this.

Comment: Using your browser’s developer tools you could have found out yourself what causes this … so get used to making use of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To remove it add the following:

```
body { margin: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also search normalize.css or reset.css and add the style before your own style.